# how to pass argument to jquery for bootstrap tooltip text from an element in the html body

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following simple markup which displays a colored bootstrap tooltip when hovering over the button in the body.  The tooltip text is currently hardcoded into the jquery function.  I want to pass the tooltip text to the jquery function from the button markup.  How to do this?  (this will eventually be asp.net markup)

```
<html>
<title>toolTips</title>
<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryScripts\jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>     
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryScripts\bootstrap.min.js"></script>     
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqueryScripts\bootstrap-combined.min.css">     

  <style type="text/css">
    .red-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {background-color: #f00;}
    .red-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color:#f00; }
  </style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(
   function(){
      $('#userNameField').tooltip({    
          'placement': 'bottom',
          'title': "...this is a test tooltip..."
       });
}); 

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" class="red-tooltip" id="userNameField" value="button1">  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `title` attribute for that:

```
<input type="submit" class="red-tooltip" id="userNameField" value="button1" title="This is the actual tooltip">
```

Here is how it works:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#userNameField').tooltip({    
    'placement': 'bottom',
    'title': "...this is a test tooltip..."
  });
});
```

```css
.red-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {background-color: #f00;}
    .red-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color:#f00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" class="red-tooltip" id="userNameField" value="button1" title="This is the actual tooltip">
```

Bootstrap's tooltip will take the value from the `title` attribute to be used as the tooltip.

Comment: very nice.  I will try this also.  If my answer I came up with doesn't work with asp.net boundfields, maybe this one will.  Many thanks

Comment: Just tried this technique -- it also worked.  Very nice to have a variety of ways to accomplish something.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tried this which appears to work -- added this script to the script section

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
```

and I added one more button to the page to use this script while the first button uses the original script:

```
<input type="submit" class="red-tooltip" value="button2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="right" title='test button2'>
```

Eventually, I will be doing this with asp.net boundfields -- trying to get away from runat="server" controls.  The title will get its text from #Eval.... in a gridview -- rows of boundfields with different title content.